# How to add a searchbar below largeTitle using wix/react-native-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, velo

I have this using [wix/react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation):

[image]

```
  static navigatorStyle = {
    navBarHideOnScroll: true,
    largeTitle: true
  }
```

How can I add a search input (without using navBarCustomView) under the large title? Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Currently it is not supported.

This feature requires setting a `searchController` to the `navigationItem` of the native view-controller. As simple as it might seem, it's actually a bit complicated due to the fact that RNN will need to expose the functionality and API of the native `UISearchController`. That said, it's possible that it will be added in the future.

Comment: There is no real workaround because this feature is simply not available. If you really need this you can always create your own native screen and use it as an “external native screen”